# How to configure apache via cloud-config?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-12.04, cloud-init, cloud-config

We have a cloud-config script to do some work on a server right after creation. (Digital Ocean droplet)

I want the script to modify the default behavior for apache, setting the **AllowOverride** to **All** *(default value is None)* for the /var/www Directory.

To do this manually, I would simply change the apache config file (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf) to the value below.

```
<Directory /var/www/>
AllowOverride All
```

However, I want to make the change ***automatically*** somehow using cloud-config.

Is there a better way to do this?

(Note: I don't want to use the ***write_files*** directive simply overwrite the entire apache2.conf file with our own custom version for fear of forward incompatibility with future apache versions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to use a full configuration management system like chef you could add this to the `runcmd:` list:

```
- sed -i '/<Directory \/var\/www\/>/ { N; N; s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/ }' /etc/apache/sites-availabl/default
```

The problem is that these simple changes increase in number and complexity and in the end you should have used chef.